# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

Tags: discord, bots, python-3.6, typeerror, discord.py

I have been trying to make a bot using python for discord. This bot adds the member to another room depending in the room s/he is in. When I tried to run the code I keep getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

This is the definition where I get the error

```
def get_sibling_role(member):
roles = member.roles; ret = None #<==there is an issue on this
for role in roles:
    if role.name == "Brothers Waiting Room":
        ret = ("Brother", role); break
    elif role.name == "Sisters Waiting Room":
        ret = ("Sister", role); break
return ret
```

#I already have member defined which returns the member ID

Can anyone help me find out the issue in my definition?

Comment: Apparently `member` is `None`. Double check your data when calling this function.

Comment: You are right, the `member` is `None`. When I tried to print it separately, it printed `None`.  I am now trying to see how to avoid getting it empty and see what is wrong on that part. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NoneType` issue is an error where many programmers face discord.py for a few main reasons

1- My own mistake in the previous problem was outside the given code. The code that I wrote was correct, however, I had two client instances defined in the same code, which made the whole program get confused, which returned none for members and for roles, so modify your discord.Client or commands.Bot constructor.

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

if you want to test and debug, I would advise printing the first member in the server by using the following code under the `on_ready():` function.

```py
print (guild.members[1])
```

---

2- The second common mistake is that people tend to not use intents, they have to use intents to get members
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html
also, you should enable them (Privileged Gateway) as explained in the previous doc in the discord portal https://discord.com/developers/applications

---

3- Update your discord.py to version 1.5.0. or higher. Make sure you're installing it to the correct environment

---

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reason is that value of member is None. To avoid that you can add a check for "not None". I am also assuming that the misalignment is because of posting the code in question rather than in the code.

```
def get_sibling_role(member):
  if member is None:
    return None

  roles = member.roles; ret = None #<==there is an issue on this
  for role in roles:
     if role.name == "Brothers Waiting Room":
        ret = ("Brother", role); break
     elif role.name == "Sisters Waiting Room":
        ret = ("Sister", role); break
  return ret
```

Comment: That's right it is empty. Now I will see how I can avoid getting the member empty. Thank you